# Extract Decimal Numbers From A List In Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to extract the decimal numbers from a string. I have a working solution, but i think it can be done in a better way,

[image]

---

The following M-Code does the work,

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table21"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.FindText(Text.Split([Column1]," "),".")),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Custom", type number}}),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Changed Type1", {"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Errors"
```

---

But I want to extract the decimal numbers from the list

[image]

---

What should I add before

```
List.FindText(Text.Split([Column1]," "),".")
```

To extract only the decimal numbers.

---

| Column1 | Expected Output |
| --- | --- |
| 100298 - 6000.2581 NG Migration & Dismantling Add | 6000.2581 |
| 101536 - 6000.2578 NG Migration & Dismantling CS 6 | 6000.2578 |
| 101944 - 6000.2578 NG Migration & Dismantling CS 6 | 6000.2578 |
| 102209 - 6000.2578 NG Migration & Dismantling CS 6 | 6000.2578 |
| 102856 - 6000.2581 NG Migration & Dismantling Add | 6000.2581 |
| 8000.8500 - car bus bicztytr | 8000.8500 |
| 8000.7072 ertefg gfhfjfgj fghfgh | 8000.7072 |
| 8000.7075 fghgfhg gfhhgjjses | 8000.7075 |
| 8000.7076 rtretretre ter gdb v dffbdtbt | 8000.7076 |
| 8000.7077 wqe ret gfn vbogf | 8000.7077 |
| 8000.8181 gfhg(per lic. for UL900) | 8000.8181 |
| 8000.8254 Mgfhghhode Licenses | 8000.8254 |
| 8000.8254 Multi-mgfhghgode Licenses | 8000.8254 |
| gfhg(per lic. for UL900) 8000.8181 | 8000.8181 |
| gfhg(per lic. for UL900) 8000.8181 | 8000.8181 |

Comment: What do you mean?  You're already extracting only the decimal numbers with the code you have.

Comment: I want to extract the decimal numbers like 8000.8181, 8000.8254 etc.

Comment: But your code already does that?

Comment: Yes, but I have to expand the list and then change the data type to decimal, next on doing that, I have to remove the error to show the expected output, so i thought there can be better way to do this

Comment: @DavidBacci is there any `M-Code` which can pull the decimals from here `List.FindText(Text.Split([Column1]," "),".")` or is it wrong I am thinking?

Comment: I see. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("nc9PS8MwGMfxt/JjJwU30tik6VEUvGxexNPcYWn+NKVrNU0n+upNN3QrIkohp/D5Js+zXs8SQmguMAcnhCwoEwke7rFy1m+Daxs89xFw3Llut21C7RqLG6Vmm6shTdg1P6WZ+DO9fQT/avM0ndpSSvLJrWB80rpiKAQjJNbF1kP2HaQrPsJ78CeQkYxC+6CNhTWlqYytYGwZzwix4TKCgyptVXW6GwEOH7w+HgTtYZXEHsoYqYIMI5vh7VUj0vhYg71srTkbOYlLDj9dvMRXalcsYFqPp2VOyOUZoyzFanBl2SqNpSt0MxrqKPo6uPnu4OwP99s3+J7k32zzCQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each   List.RemoveItems ( List.Transform( List.FindText(Text.Split([Column1]," "),"."), each Text.Select(_, {"0".."9", "."})) , {"."}){0}, type number )
in
    #"Added Custom"
```